# Privacy error for wrong domain

Tags: url, ssl, iis, url-rewriting, certificate

i have a wildcard ssl certificate installed on my iis server
i use it for my domain, mydomain.com
multiple external domains and multiple sub domains (mydomain.com)
are pointing to my website
when i try to browse to https://www.extdomain.com (for example)
i got Privacy error: Your connection is not private
i need to redirect for https to http only for external domains
how can i make it? 
i tried to fix it with url rewrite
i want to use th ssl certificate only for my sub domains
any suggestions how to fix that?

Thanks,
Yosi

Comment: Your question is confusing.do you want external domain to be on https? To fix the mixed content warning you get, You may have absolute urls to resources in http in your html.you need to remive that. Also all the sub domains,shud be https?

Comment: i need the external domains will not use the ssl
and the sub domains will use the ssl

Answer (score 0):

As understand you want:

- All requests, which is coming to (mydomain.com and other subdomains) should be served with https. Because you have wildcard SSL
- All requests to other domains (domain1.com and etc) should be redirected to HTTP because you do not have SSL certificate for them.

This rules will do that for you *(you just need to replace domain.com with your domain name)*:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to http" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"/>
</rule>
```